# Recursive array search

Tags: plugin-development, php, array, function

I've got a plugin where I've written a simple recursive array search to find an array within a nested/multidimensional array which contains a certain value.

```
private function arraySearch($haystack,$needle,$depth = 1)
{
    foreach($haystack AS $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists('title',$value) && strtolower($value['title']) == strtolower($needle)) {
            return $value;
        } elseif(is_array($value)) {
            $depth++;
            $this->arraySearch($value,$needle,$depth);
        }
    }
}
```

With some logging within this function I can see that it works and returns at the correct time but when I call it in my plugin methods the response is empty.

For example, if I wanted to get an array which contains a `title` key and the value for this is `venue`, I'd type:

```
$result = $this->arraySearch($array,'Venue');
```

Applied to the following array:

```
Array
(
    [pages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [elements] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => text
                                    [isRequired] => 1
                                    [name] => question1
                                    [title] => Venue
                                )

                            [1] => Array
```

So this should return the array `$array['pages'][0]['elements][0]` but $result` seems to be empty.

Any suggestions?

Cole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```php
$this->arraySearch($value,$needle,$depth);
```

should be

```php
return $this->arraySearch($value,$needle,$depth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ArrayHelper class that comes with Yii and is extended by Craft. It may very well do all that you need

Hmmmm never mind that might be Craft 3